# How to setup the onClickListener for the imageview in the Listview

Tags: android

There are a lot of discussions for this topic. But none of them work for me.
I implemented a customized ListView with an `ImageView` in the `ListView` and the `ListView` is extended from the `ListFragment`. My ImageView is clickable so that when the user click the ImageView, the Camera activity is activated and the ImageView is updated with the image captured. The XML is as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_background_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_view_description"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/icons_preview"
            />

    </LinearLayout>  

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now is I need to differentiate the user's click which is for the list item or for the ImageView. I setup `onListItemClick` that can catch user's click for the list item in the ListView, but when I click for the ImageView, it does not work. How can I detect when the user click the ImageView. My ListFragment class is as shown below.

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {
    private customList_Adaptor adapter;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 0;
    private static final int RESULT_OK = 0;
    private static MyListFragmentInterface mCallback = null;
    static Context thisListFragmentContext = null;
    private String[] mListItems;
    private TrackerDBAdapter dbHelper;
    private List<String> listIDs;   
    public MyListFragment() {   

    }

    public MyListFragment(MyListFragmentInterface callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_fragment, container, false); 
        dbHelper = new TrackerDBAdapter(getActivity());
        dbHelper.open();
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllTrackerInTheList();
        mListItems = new String[dbHelper.getLastInsertedID()];
        thisListFragmentContext = getActivity();
        int i = 0;
        for(cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext())
            mListItems[i++] = cursor.getString(1);

        dbHelper.close();
        listIDs = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        listIDs = Arrays.asList(mListItems);
        adapter = new customList_Adaptor(thisListFragmentContext, R.layout.list_row, listIDs);
        ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);      
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);     



        return view;
    }

    public void addNewTrackerintoListDisplay(TrackerInfo newTracker){
        mListItems = append(mListItems, newTracker.getIdnumber());      
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            mListItems));
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private String[] append(String[] mListItems2, String idnumber) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final int N = mListItems2.length;
        mListItems2 = Arrays.copyOf(mListItems2, N + 1);
        mListItems2[N] = idnumber;
        return mListItems2;
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        mCallback.itemSelected(mListItems[position]);
    }


}
```

My adapter class is as follow.

```
public class customList_Adaptor extends ArrayAdapter<String>{


    protected static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 0;

    private Context context;

    private List<String> listIDs = new ArrayList<String>();

    public customList_Adaptor(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.setContext(context);
        this.listIDs = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(listIDs != null)
            return listIDs.size();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(listIDs != null)
            return listIDs.get(arg0);
        else
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(vi==null){
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
            viewHolder.id=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
            viewHolder.thumbnailImage=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
            viewHolder.arrow=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_arrow);
            vi.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else
            viewHolder=(ViewHolder) vi.getTag();


//      viewHolder.thumbnailImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
//          
//          @Override
//          public void onClick(View arg0) {
//              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
//              ((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
//          }
//          
//      }); 

        // Setting all values in listview
        viewHolder.id.setText(listIDs.get(position));

        return vi;
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


}
```

Comment: put your adapter class ...answer for u

Comment: @Tony Stark I put my adapter class.

Comment: what u want explain somewhat more friend

Comment: whether u need to click and select image for the listitem

Comment: What I want is when I click the ImageView on the ListView, I want to catch that click so that I can activate the Camera Activity and capture image and load it onto the ImageView. Now can't catch the ImageView click. I can catch only the click on the row of the ListView inside the onListItemClick().

Comment: yes whether I click or touch the ImageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment implements OnItemClickListener {
        private customList_Adaptor adapter;
        private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 0;
        private static final int RESULT_OK = 0;
        private static MyListFragmentInterface mCallback = null;
        static Context thisListFragmentContext = null;
        private String[] mListItems;
        private TrackerDBAdapter dbHelper;
        private List<String> listIDs;   
        public MyListFragment() {   

        }

        public MyListFragment(MyListFragmentInterface callback) {
            mCallback = callback;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_fragment, container, false); 
            dbHelper = new TrackerDBAdapter(getActivity());
            dbHelper.open();
            Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllTrackerInTheList();
            mListItems = new String[dbHelper.getLastInsertedID()];
            thisListFragmentContext = getActivity();
            int i = 0;
            for(cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext())
                mListItems[i++] = cursor.getString(1);

            dbHelper.close();
            listIDs = new ArrayList<String>(); 
            listIDs = Arrays.asList(mListItems);
            adapter = new customList_Adaptor(thisListFragmentContext, R.layout.list_row, listIDs,this);
            ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);      
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);     

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

            return view;
        }

        public void addNewTrackerintoListDisplay(TrackerInfo newTracker){
            mListItems = append(mListItems, newTracker.getIdnumber());      
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), 
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mListItems));
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private String[] append(String[] mListItems2, String idnumber) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final int N = mListItems2.length;
            mListItems2 = Arrays.copyOf(mListItems2, N + 1);
            mListItems2[N] = idnumber;
            return mListItems2;
        }

            @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
             mCallback.itemSelected(mListItems[position]);

        }
        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {


        }

      public void imagepos(int i){
       //onImage click comes here
       }

    }
-----------------------------------------------------
 public class customList_Adaptor extends ArrayAdapter<String>{


        protected static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 0;

        private Context context;
        MyListFragment mMyListFragment;
        private List<String> listIDs = new ArrayList<String>();

        public customList_Adaptor(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                List<String> objects, MyListFragment mMyListFragment) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            this.setContext(context);
            this.listIDs = objects;
            this.mMyListFragment= mMyListFragment
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(listIDs != null)
                return listIDs.size();
            else
                return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(listIDs != null)
                return listIDs.get(arg0);
            else
                return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi=convertView;
            ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if(vi==null){
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
                viewHolder.id=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
                viewHolder.thumbnailImage=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
                viewHolder.arrow=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_arrow);
                vi.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            else
                viewHolder=(ViewHolder) vi.getTag();


          viewHolder.thumbnailImage.setOnClickListener(new onMyClick(position));

            // Setting all values in listview
            viewHolder.id.setText(listIDs.get(position));

            return vi;
        }

public class onMyClick implements OnClickListener {

        private final int pos;
        public onMyClick(int pos) {
            this.pos = pos;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mMyListFragment.imagepos(pos);
        }

    }

        public Context getContext() {
            return context;
        }

        public void setContext(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }


    }
```

Comment: I set the breakpoints inside onListItemClick and onItemClick. When a row in the ListView is clicked, it was caught inside onListItemClick. But when I click ImageView, it is not caught in both of them.

Comment: check now .. on image click imagepos will call in mainfrag

Answer (score 1):

use **onItemClickListener** instead of **onListItemClick**

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mCallback.itemSelected(mListItems[position]);

    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Adapter class there will be getView that contains imageview 
in that view create onclick listener for the imageview

```
Imageview imageView=(ImageView)view.findviewByid(your id);

imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Comment: Yeah that approach is implementing inside the ArrayAdapter, so to get image back from the camera with startActivityForResult is not possible. That is why I need to start the camera activity from the ListFragment class and get the image back with startActivityForResult when the user click the ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onItemClickListener()` for the listview and you can remove `android:clickable="true"` from Image View. The other way is to set `onClickListener()` for the image view in `getView()` if you are customizing the adapter. but try with first approach.

Comment: I tested both, only the second approach can catch the ImageView click. The first one can't catch ImageView click. But the second one is implemented inside the ArrayAdapter, so to get image back from the camera with startActivityForResult is not possible.